# parse csv file in gaej using blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, csv, blobstore

I have uploaded a csv file to blobstore using blobstoreService.now how can i parse this csv file using blobkey.that is how I read this file in a inputstream kind of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the file [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) via [BlobKey(String blobKey)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobKey.html) as constructor parameter to [BlobstoreInputStream(BlobKey blobKey)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/index?com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreInputStream.html).

For example:

```
BlobstoreInputStream is = new BlobstoreInputStream(new BlobKey("YOU_BLOB_KEY"));
```

For parsing [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file, you can consider use [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)'s [CSVReader](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.html).

For example:

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
List<String[]> rows = csvReader.readAll();
```

Comment: Thanks,I was looking for this only